# How to display the name of the field that changes depending on the execution of the method? JDeveloper, Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

There is such a problem. I have a method in NotifBean class - checkUnprocessedNotifications() which returns 1 or 0. The code is below. Now, I go to the application page rootPage.jsf. This application has a header. This header has a Documents field. If this method returns a value of 1, then the Documents field in the header should change to NOT PROCESSED, if 0 is returned, then the field should remain under the name DOCUMENTS.

NotifBean class

```
        public Integer checkUnprocessedNotifications() {
        DCIteratorBinding iterB = ADFBindingsUtil.getIterator("NotificationsInboxV1Iterator");
        int count = 0;
        iterB.executeQuery(); 
        Row[] rows = iterB.getAllRowsInRange();
        for (Row row : rows) {
            log.warn("rows = "+Arrays.toString(rows));
            String status = (String) row.getAttribute("Status");
            if (status != null && status.equals("Pending")) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count>0){
            return 1; 
        }else{
        return 0; 
        }
    }
```

rootPage.jsf

```
<af:link text="#{rootPageController.securityData.documentsViewable ? 
    (pageFlowScope.NotifBean.checkUnprocessedNotifications() > 0 ? 'NOT PROCESSED' : 'DOCUMENTS') : 'DOCUMENTS'}" id="l7"
 rendered="#{rootPageController.securityData.documentsViewable}"
 immediate="true" action="#{rootPageController.documentsRegionLaunch}"
 inlineStyle="font-size:large;font-weight:#{rootPageController.documentsSelected ? 'Bold' : ''};margin-left:20px;"/>
```

The problem is that when I go to the application site, the field in the header does not change, but the DOCUMENTS remain. Please, help!

Oracle JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.0.0

Comment: Can you clearify the problem, please? Quote "The problem is that when I go to the application site, the field in the header does not change, but the DOCUMENTS remain. Please, help!" I don't see a header. You show us an af:link. What do you mean by "...field in the header does not change..."? Should it change?

Comment: @TimoHahn Thanks for the feedback. I apologize for the incomplete explanation of the problem. I already solved it. Thank you!